# Generated corrupt large ply file - how to find the error

Tags: mesh, eof, meshlab, ply-file-format

I just wrote a java class to generate meshes from a cylinder list stored to a ply file. I tested the files with a hand generated list of 3 cylinders. The resulting file I can open both in Meshlab and Cloudcompare. 
When I use the class in my real program I have to write a mesh for more than 13000 cylinders.
Cloudcompare gives me the following error : *Reading error(no access right?)*

Meshlab this one :  *error details, unexptected eof*

I already checked if my ply file contains the exact number of vertices and faces defined in the header. I also assured, there are no nan (checked for 'n','a', etc in winedit) values contained.

I can reproduce the errors with my test file from the 3 hand made cylinder file by deleting the last line. But as mentioned earlier, I already checked if the line numbers are correct (might be an empty line not caught by my eyes though, as scrolling down half a million lines is impossible).

So are there any programs available to parse the ply file for errors? Open source tools would be appreciated here. Or are the files just to large? 436302 lines to be exact. I use ascii version of ply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a non open source tool called nugraf, which provides information about the corrupted line numbers. 
Java seems to print NAN with '?'. For this char i did not check, so problem seems to be solved and I can debug my java software now again.